# MSO is not being returned in StackAuth's /users/{id}/associated route

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackauth, associated

In looking into a [StackFlair](http://stackflair.com) issue, I have discovered that MSO is not being returned as part of a user's associated accounts.  Please see my [associated accounts](http://stackauth.com/1.0/users/3f0eac82-1801-410d-b334-234c18ddeeeb/associated) according to the api.  Note that there is no mention of a MSO account, however I clearly have [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rchern).

I've noticed a lower rep being displayed for a few days, I just hadn't gotten around to looking into what was causing the lower rep display.  I'd say it has been like this since at least Friday if that helps any.

Comment: Seems [status-completed].  Close as too localized?

Comment: side effect of some of the fallout from new associations code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.